# Add Space between two string in C

Tags: c, string

hello im trying to add a space between two strings and strcopy them into a variable

in php we could just add them with a +

```
front_name = "hello";
back_name = "world";
full_name = strcpy(m[index].p.something, front_name + " " + backname);
// should output hello world
```

**what is the equivalent or the right way to do it in c?**

Comment: If you're on Linux, you could look at `asprintf()`; it will allocate the correct amount of space for you, and return you the pointer to that space (with the data formatted, of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sprintf would be ideal provided the buffer that the strings are copied to is large anough:

e.g.

```
   char buffer[512]; 
   sprintf(buffer, "%s %s", front_name, backname);
```

Comment: i didnt know that there is buffer.

Comment: in your case buffer would be m[index].p.something

Comment: ah i see, there is no example in stackoverflow that shows in printf(buffer, etc). again thankyou. i was thinking to use strcat 3 times.

Comment: strcat would be fine. I assume that one sprintf call would be quicker than several strcaats.

Comment: Never use `sprintf`. Only `snprintf`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `result` has enough space, use this:

```
sprintf(result, "%s %s", front_name, backname);
```